# Does Firefox 50.1.0 support Java applets?

Tags: java, firefox

i have old Java applet started on my page. It worked in FF until its last update. In previous version, the warning was displayed before starting this applet, but now it's not working. The popup is displayed: **"Java Plug-in is not supported by this browser.** .

How to turn JAVA applets on in newest FF?

Comment: "Old Java applet" - be aware that JDK 9 will deprecate applets.  It's time to start thinking about moving off that tired technology.  It's 1995 vintage.

Comment: OK, Im almost ready:). Thanks.

Comment: "almost" - there's your problem.  You won't be able to wait another 20 years.  FF and other browsers will decide for you.

Comment: I don't think Java is gone completely in Firefox 50, but [it will be going away for good in Firefox 52](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2016/plug-in-support-has-been-dropped-other-than-flash/). Similar things are happening with Chrome. So the sooner you move away from applets the better, really.

Comment: it was application I took over from other developer, but I have ready solution but it's "under review" now. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Firefox 50.1.0 supports Java applets. The problem is Java no longer supports Java applets because they are deemed a "security risk". 
 If you really want to run a Java applet in a browser, you will need to add it to the "Exception Site List" under the Security tab of the Java Control Panel. Also, the checkbox labeled "Enable Java content in the browser" will need to be checked.